# Deploying pwa to GH pages

Tags: deployment, progressive-web-apps, github-pages

I bumped into problems, trying to deploy my pwa to GH pages.
Service worker is not available.

I try to register it the following way

```
 navigator​.​serviceWorker 
 ​                ​.​register​(​"sw.js"​)
```

The problems in the wrong path to sw.js

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use full path to your gh page.

```
username.github.io/repo/sw.js
```